# Why is there more content found when converting a pdf to jpeg?

Tags: pdf, jpeg, pdf-conversion

When I convert a pdf file to JPG format, there are extra contents at the top of the image but this content is not found in the pdf file.
[image]

The above screenshot if for the pdf file.[image]

The above image is of the jpg file ( converted from pdf - the first image).

Any idea why there is some extra content coming for this file ? This happens only for this file. For all other files I convert using the pdf2image python library (or any method), the jpg is similiar to the pdf. Please help ?

Comment: That file has registration and crop marks. I do not know pdf2image but it is obviously including these areas outside the printable region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra region that is shown when converting to an image format is called the non printable region. In the pdf file, only the printable region is visible. The non printable region will not be visible in the pdf file. When converted to another format (eg: jpeg/png), the non printable region is also converted and is shown in the image file. You will need to crop the image using the markings provided above the printable region (+).